# How to turn off saved data popup in edge

Tags: microsoft-edge

[saved data popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGGK0.png)

As per screenshot, It is showing saved data pop up which we have entered earlier, how to not show this popup when we click on this pop up ?

Answer (score 2):

I've tried several methods of fixing this issue.

These didn't work:

- https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftedge/forum/all/how-to-turn-off-saved-data-popup-in-edge/0135e4ad-8ab4-4c82-bf2e-867027d05f16
- https://www.isunshare.com/windows-10/turn-on-or-off-save-form-entries-in-microsoft-edge.html (very early version of Edge, so not useful)
- The `edge://settings/search` solution

Here's the steps that worked for me.

- Paste this URL into the addressbar:

`edge://settings/personalinfo`

- Turn off the following:

  - Save and fill basic info
  - Save and fill custom info

And because I'm a tech writer, I also documented them here: [issue MS Edge saved info popup](https://github.com/ljsinclair/ljsinclair/blob/main/issues-and-fixes/issue-ms-edge-saved-info-popup.md)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which exact version of the MS Edge browser you are using. I am assuming you are using the one of recent latest versions.

If you mean when you are clicking on the Address bar, it shows the previous search results and you would like to hide them.

I suggest you paste `edge://settings/search` in the address bar and press the Enter key.

After that Try to toggle the option **Show me search and site suggestions using my typed characters** and **Show me suggestions from history, favorites, and other data on this device using my typed characters** to disabled.

[image]

Let me know whether this suggestion helps to fix your issue.

If the issue still persists, please try to provide more information and provide the exact steps for producing the said issue. I could try provide you further suggestions.